# Flash Actionscript 3.0 Audio Scrubber

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs5

So I've been working on a Flash audio player for my website, and I'm trying to make a scrubber for the player. With the scrubber, a person will be able to drag the little bubble to fast-forward or rewind the song to a certain part.

What I have tried so far is this: I have made a player head that moves in a designated line proportionally to how much the progress bar has moved. Since I have an instance of a progress bar, progressBar, and a sprite progressBubble (aka the player head), they do not seem to integrate very well.

My question is, is there some kind of player head object that one can use specifically for progress bars? In any case, how can this scrubber be done?

(And I am new/not a big fan of Flash, and I have Googled, YouTubed, looked at Adobe's API,etc. for quite some time now and I can't figure out how to do this. If you can help me, you'll be my hero and I'll be grateful.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are many great widget kits. One of my favorites is at http://www.minimalcomps.com/?page_id=5